# How to edit Item's Item Properties in a custom Template using Python?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, print-composer

I am trying to automate the process of creating Map Composers in qgis but I am running in to the problem of editing the contents of a Template that I am using.[image]

For example, how would I edit Map 0, LEGEND, EXHIBIT NUMBER, and LOGO just using python? Is there a specific library I need to be able to process the template?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you need to change? In general, the QGIS2 Python API for Composer is not very good. The QGIS3 Python API should be much better in this regard.